# How do i know which exceptions to catch in a core function that throws in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch

I'm implementing `public class func JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions) throws -> AnyObject` But have no idea which exceptions i can catch? My colleague at work suggests debugging the error when i catch it. But there must be another way to find out before running the code?

Comment: This method can throw "an `NSError` object that describes the problem". That's all.

Comment: Ok. so in the core functions there are probably no other types of exeptions?

Comment: I think so. We can think of it as of ObjC legacy.

Comment: Just have to learn to live with it :) i guess

Answer (score 0):

Here throws is just wrapper around NSError

Usually I use this function like this:

```
if let yourObject = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as? TObjectTypeYouExpected
{                
            // other code here
}
```

You can also use it this way:

```
do {
    yourObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: options)
} catch let error as NSError {
     print("Some error: \(error)")
     data = nil
}
```